# Output linux CLI output to a datatable in python

Tags: python, pandas, linux

In Python, what is the best way to take the output from a CLI command and add it into a datatable?

I've been using `pandas` for the datatable, but I can't get the right result.  I'd like to take the results of the command and manipulate the data in python in a datatable of some type and then add further processing.  I've been trying a few variations of the below code, but without success:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
cmd = "ls -al"
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', cmd])
for line in output.splitlines():
    data_frame = pd.append([data_frame, line])
```

Comment: [read_commandline](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.read_commandline) from pyjanitor can be handy

Comment: Why are you unhappy with your code? What is missing?

Comment: @pts pd.append was throwing an error.  I think I'm just using the wrong combination of processes to generate the output, loop through the lines and add to datatable.

Comment: The problem is with the last line (containing `pd.append`), unrelated to the external command. First try to populate `data_frame` with constant, fake lines. As soon as that works, you will be able to fix the last line. Your use of `subprocess` is already correct.

Comment: Instead of `['bash', '-c', 'ls -al']`, it's faster and more secure to avoid the shell, like this: `['ls', '-al']`. However, changing only this won't fix your problem.